# Prevent value to be inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, input

I'm doing a js function that will prevent some input data to be inserted within an `input textbox` (only DDDDDD,DD for example):

```
// decimal
$('.is-decimal').keydown(function (e) {
    // prevent to insert non-decimal number (number with comma, max 2 digits after comma)
    var elem = $(this);
    var value = elem.val();

    var regex = /^\d+,?\d{0,2}$/;
    if (!regex.test(value)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

but I can't use keydown: first time is empty, so it won't check the following char.

Which method should I use? `keyup` is later (so it's just inserted); the same with `.on("input propertychange", function ()`

EDIT: my best attempt:

```
// decimal
$('.is-decimal').on("input propertychange", function (e) {
    var elem = $(this);
    var value = elem.val();

    // prevent to insert non-decimal number (number with comma, max 2 digits after comma)
    var regex = /^\d+,?\d{0,2}$/;
    if (!regex.test(value)) {
        elem.val(elem.attr('data-actual-value'));

        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        elem.attr("data-actual-value", value);
    }
});
```

Comment: try `.change`? :)

Comment: or just test if value is empty before testing your regex..

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs change doesn't works with input textbox

Comment: @Kaddath: but keydown is "before" evalutating the new char. So it will be always empty the frst time. The problem is later, if I insert a invalid value

Answer (score 1):

You define a `lastValidValue` can use `keyup` and `change` events to check the newly entered value and if the new value is invalid change it back to the `lastValidValue`.

Note: You modify the value without triggering `keyup` and `keydown` e.g. right-click and paste

Here's an example

```
let decField = document.querySelector('#decimal')

let lastValidValue = ''
const regex = /^\d+,?\d{0,2}$/;

const eventHandler = e => {
    if( event.target.value.match(regex) ) {
        lastValidValue = event.target.value
    }
    else {
        event.target.value = lastValidValue
    }
}

decField.addEventListener('keyup', eventHandler)
decField.addEventListener('change', eventHandler)
```

**Edit**: here's an example with multiple fields using `data-regex` attribute to have individual regexes

```js
const eventHandler = e => {
    let regex = new RegExp(event.target.dataset.regex);
    
    if( regex.test(event.target.value) ) {
        event.target.dataset.lastValidValue = event.target.value
    }
    else {
        event.target.value = event.target.dataset.lastValidValue || ''
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[data-regex]').forEach(field => {
    field.addEventListener('keyup', eventHandler);
    field.addEventListener('change', eventHandler);
})
```

```html
<input type="text" data-regex="^\d+,?\d{0,2}$" placeholder="digits" />
<input type="text" data-regex="^[\w\s]+$" placeholder="text" />
<input type="text" data-regex="^\W+$" placeholder="special chars" />
```

Comment: `.change` doesn't trigger the change of the input. Yes, I need also copy and paste (which is covered by keydown)

Comment: It's triggered once the value is changed and the focus moves out of the field

Comment: I need to make this for multiple variables, using jquery handlers and such. not for a specific input. somethings more flexible :)

Comment: @markzzz I've added an example with multiple fields